# execute time builtin automatically after each command in zsh (like `set time` in tcsh)

Tags: performance, time, zsh

In [`tcsh`](http://mdoc.su/f/tcsh.1), there's a pretty useful feature that automatically lets you print the `time` statistics for each command.  It can be enabled with a very simple `set time` to set the "Special shell variable" by the name of `time`:

```
tcsh$ set time
tcsh$ sleep 1
0.000u 0.015s 0:01.01 0.9%      0+0k 0+0io 2241pf+0w
tcsh$ sleep 1 && sleep 0.1
0.000u 0.000s 0:01.01 0.0%      0+0k 0+0io 2241pf+0w
0.000u 0.015s 0:00.11 9.0%      0+0k 0+0io 2243pf+0w
tcsh$
```

```
tcsh$ man tcsh | fgrep -A2 'If set to a number,'
       time    If set to a number, then the time builtin (q.v.) executes auto‐
               matically after each command which takes more  than  that  many
               CPU seconds.  If there is a second word, it is used as a format
2.257u 0.319s 0:01.52 168.4%    0+0k 0+0io 35517pf+0w
tcsh$
```

I've tried looking for a similar solution for `zsh`, but I cannot find such option in [`zshoptions(1)`](http://mdoc.su/f/zshoptions.1) or any other page, and all I get are extensive configuration settings altering the underlying functions of the shell (apart from `EXTENDED_HISTORY` and `INC_APPEND_HISTORY_TIME`, which, whilst very useful, aren't the same what I'm looking for).

Does zsh not have a similar option?  Is there no way to print execution time for each command in a set number of commands?

Answer (score 5):

The option is actually in [`zshparam`](http://mdoc.su/f/zshparam.1), not [`zshoptions`](http://mdoc.su/f/zshoptions.1), and is called `REPORTTIME`.

```
zsh% REPORTTIME=
% REPORTTIME=
zsh% sleep 1
sleep 1  0.02s user 0.01s system 2% cpu 1.039 total
zsh% sleep 1 && sleep 0.1
sleep 1  0.03s user 0.01s system 3% cpu 1.094 total
sleep 0.1  0.01s user 0.01s system 17% cpu 0.130 total
zsh%
```

```
% man zshparam | fgrep -B1 -A3 'If nonnegative'
       REPORTMEMORY
              If nonnegative, commands whose maximum resident set size
              (roughly speaking, main memory usage) in kilobytes is greater
              than this value have timing statistics reported.  The format
              used to output statistics is the value of the TIMEFMT parameter,
--
       REPORTTIME
              If nonnegative, commands whose combined user and system
              execution times (measured in seconds) are greater than this
              value have timing statistics printed for them.  Output is
              suppressed for commands executed within the line editor,
man zshparam  0.06s user 0.01s system 94% cpu 0.071 total
fgrep -B1 -A3 'If nonnegative'  0.02s user 0.02s system 67% cpu 0.069 total
%
```